# How global fixtures work in BOOST.Test?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-test

I have started using BOOST recently for unit testing.
Just need one clarification on global fixtures.

When it got executed? ... for each test module, or each test suite or each test case?
Will it be the first before any thing else got executed?

I am using the `BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE` for writing my tests.

Answer (score 2):

global fixtures are executed once per module since they are defined at [file scope](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/fixture/global.html). Typically I use them to initialize logging or a database connection should my unit tests need them.

Comment: how to use the same global fixture in multiple files?